# Are there any numbers so that $a*b\equiv 0 \pmod n$ but not $a\equiv 0 \pmod n$ and not$ b \equiv 0 (\pmod n) $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are there any numbers so that $a*b\equiv 0 \pmod n$ but not $a\equiv 0 \pmod n$ and not$ b \equiv 0 (\pmod n) $?

$n=\{2,3,4,6,7\}$

After trying some numbers I would say no, but is there any proof for that?

Comment: What happens when you choose $n=6$, $a=2$, $b=3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there are. For example, $2 \times 3 = 6 \equiv 0 $ (mod $6$)

In fact, for every composite (i.e. non-prime) number, this will be the case: if $n = ab$, then $ab \equiv 0 $ (mod $n$)

However, if $n$ is prime, then you're right that this cannot happen - since if $ab \equiv 0$ (mod $p$) for some prime $p$, then by definition,  $ p | ab$, so since p is prime, $p|a$ or $p|b$ so we must have $a \equiv 0$ (mod $p$) or $b \equiv 0$ (mod $p$).